# Dependencies between shared libraries in the same Debian packages

Tags: debian, dpkg, dependencies, dynamic-linking

Suppose I want to create a package with multiple shared libraries - call it `libfoo`, which contains `liba.so.1` and `libb.so.1`. Now, say `liba.so.1` uses a symbol from `libb.so.1`. If I compile like this, then everything is OK:

```
cc   -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libb.so.1 -o libb.so.1 libb.c
cc   -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,liba.so.1 -o liba.so.1 liba.c libb.so.1
```

However, that takes some extra work (I have to manually figure out the dependencies and code them into my makefile, and scons doesn't seem to do this automatically). Compiling the easy way creates an interesting problem:

```
cc   -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libb.so.1 -o libb.so.1 libb.c
cc   -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,liba.so.1 -o liba.so.1 liba.c
```

Now `liba.so.1` doesn't have `libb.so.1` in its `DT_NEEDED` header (visible using `objdump -p`), and when building a debian package I get the following message (and this step takes MUCH longer):

```
dh_shlibdeps
   dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol b used by debian/libfoo1/usr/lib/liba.so.1 found in none of the libraries.
```

This happens because symbol `b` is defined in `libb.so.1`, but `dpkg-shlibdeps` has no way of knowing that.

I should note that there doesn't seem to be a real problem here - the actual binary has both `liba` and `libb` as `DT_NEEDED`, and they are both loaded at run-time... have been for years. This problem only arose when trying to create a proper, cleanly-building debian package.

How should I solve this? (*should* I solve this?) The libraries really should (TM) be in the same debian package. (For bonus points, solve for circular dependencies, i.e. `libb` also uses a symbol from `liba`).

Comment: Stupid question: why do you need libb and liba to be two different libs?

Comment: I'm packaging someone else's code.

Comment: Or if you’ve written a library with python bindings, you’re have two libraries as well.